# Check contents of UTF-8 string

Tags: java, utf-8

I have a original string:

String originalStr = "Đây là chuỗi gốc";

I have another string too:

String str1 = "Đây";

String str2 = "Day";

i wanna check both string str1 and str2 is contained by originalStr.
Have any idea?

Thank for all comments;

**I fixed it. Follow code:**

```
public String convertUTF8String(String _originalString){
    String resultString = StringUtils.stripAccents(_originalString);
    return resultString.replace('Đ', 'D').replace('đ', 'd');
}
```

NOTE: import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

You can download Commons Lang [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test if a string is contains in another string without the diacritics, you can use Apache common lang : http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#stripAccents%28java.lang.String%29.

```
public boolean isStringContained(String src, String sub) {
  sub = StringUtils.stripAccents(sub);
  src = StringUtils.stripAccents(src)
  return src.contains(sub);
}
```

And then you can use the function :

```
isStringContained("Đây là chuỗi gốc", "Đây"); // returns true
isStringContained("Đây là chuỗi gốc", "Day"); // returns true
```

Answer (score 1):

If you write and save your .java file with UTF-8 encoding then you can use simple string [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method, here is the sample that i ran:

```
   public static void main (String args[]) {
    String originalStr = "Đây là chuỗi gốc"; 
    String str1 = "Đây";
    String str2 = "Day";
    System.out.println(originalStr.contains(str1));
    System.out.println(originalStr.contains(str2));
}
```

Here is the output, which is correct:

> true
>
> false

**EDIT after the comment**

Both of them are two different strings and hence the result is true & false. Java does not have intelligence to translate the strings and compare. "Đây" & "Day" are two different strings although they have the same meaning. If you want to achieve that both of them are same then you should write a method to translate the strings and then compare. In that case the meaning of both the strings will be same and hence the result will be true. Or you can have your own method called translateAndCompare to achieve the desired result.

Comment: @TranQuocHung I have updated the resolution as my comment was too long to fit here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it's not good for me. I had editted the question within the anwser. may be helped you in the future!!!

Answer (score 0):

The safest way is probably to strip all accents from the strings and compare them that way. For example:

```
Pattern ACCENTS_PATTERN = Pattern.compile( "[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]+" );
String originalStr = "Đây là chuỗi gốc";
String str1 = "Đây";
String str2 = "Day";

System.out.println( "Is str1 in originalStr? : " + originalStr.contains( str1 ) );
System.out.println( "Is str2 in originalStr? : " + originalStr.contains( str2 ) );

String originalNorm = ACCENTS_PATTERN.matcher( 
    Normalizer.normalize( originalStr, Normalizer.Form.NFD ) )
        .replaceAll( "" );

System.out.println( "The normalized string is " + originalNorm );
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't quite get you all the way there as the output is as follows:

```
Is str1 in originalStr? : true
Is str2 in originalStr? : false
The normalized string is Đay la chuoi goc
```

As you can see, there's still a dash through the first D. However, if you can work out what the Unicode group is that the letter belongs to then you can add it to the `ACCENTS_PATTERN` and hopefully that'll work.

Comment: I'm afraid not, as I don't know which Unicode group it belong to. If you can find that out and add it to the ACCENTS_PATTERN, then you might get further.